# Why is my update so slow compared to select?

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB 10.2.21 on Amazon RDS InnoDB

I am running a convoluted update (lots of subqueries in the where statement). And it takes many minutes to complete.
If I change the update to select, it takes about 1 second.

If I run the update several times it takes the same time, even if only the first run actually changes anything (~4000 rows).

The query pops up in slow queries and rows_examined is billions. Lock time is 0.

I'm not at liberty to share the exact query but it is something like this:

```
update things
set status='hidden'
where id not in (select thing_id from other_table where some condition)
  and id not in (select thing_id from yet another table ...)
```

I am fully aware that this is not that much information.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 2):

- 10.2 is probably using an older Optimizer for `UPDATE`.  It was not as smart as the Optimizer for `SELECT`.  (No, I don't have anything more specific than that.)
- Avoid `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` -- it is notorious for being inefficient.  Since you are seeing "billions" of rows_examined, I suspect it this confirms my above bullet item.  The old Optimizer would rerun the subquery each time it needed to test for `IN`.
- Try to turn the query into a "multi-table `UPDATE`" that uses `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` instead of `NOT IN`.
- It may be practical to use `NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM other_table WHERE some_condition AND thing_id = outer.id )`

Comment: Thank you for a very good answer to a bad question. :-)

Answer (score -1):

> ... it takes many minutes to complete.
> If I change the update to select, it takes about 1 second.

How long does it take you to *read* a book?
How long would it take you to *write* [a copy of] that same book?

*Reading* stuff from a database means getting data blocks into the Buffer Cache, sprinting around a few "pointers" between records and sending the data back to the client.  Easy!

*Writing* stuff in a database involves *actual* disk writes (to the Transaction log), updating data blocks in the Buffer Cache and then writing those blocks back out to the data files.  Lots [and *lots*] of work and that takes longer.

> If I run the update several times it takes the same time, even if only the first run actually changes anything (~4000 rows).

What makes you think the database is doing anything different on each of those runs?
Your database *will not* compare the "before" and "after" values of every field and *only* change the ones that are genuinely different.  If you *say* "update", then it *will* "update" - even if it's winding up with the *same* value - with all the disk activity that goes with it.

As to your particular query, you *might* get better performance comparing against only *one* sub-select:

```
. . . 
where id not in 
( select thing_id from other_table where some-condition
  union all 
  select thing_id from yet-another-table ...
)
```

This might allow the database to use better indexing options than having to second-guess itself, checking whether each id is `not this and not that`.

Comment: Some of this was useful, but the majority is not. Updates are not normally 1000x slower  so you book writing analogy isn't valid. The second time I run the update it doesn't update any rows, it doesn't write the same value again. All rows are excluded in the where clause. So that is is also invalid. I will check the union part though.